# Groovy: Accessing variables from within .eachRow() call to populate percentage calculation

Tags: sql, groovy

I currently have two queries which find specific values, which I need to gather the results from and calculate a percentage. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to access the specific variables within each queries .eachRow() call, in order to populate my percentage calculation method.

The eachRow calls are as follows:

```
def resultOne = db.eachRow(firstQuery, ["${startDate} 00:00:00".toString(),  ${endDate} 23:59:59".toString()]) {
    String ticketsMetric = it.metricName
    String ticketsValue = it.ticketValue.intValue()
    reportMetricsWithValues[ticketsMetric] = ticketsValue
    table.addData([metric:ticketsMetric, value: ticketsValue])
}

def resultTwo = db.eachRow(secondQuery, ["${startDate} 00:00:00".toString(), "${endDate} 23:59:59".toString()]) {
    String ticketsMetric = it.metricName
    String ticketsValue = it.ticketValue.intValue()
    reportMetricsWithValues[ticketsMetric] = ticketsValue
    table.addData([metric:ticketsMetric, value: ticketsValue])
}
```

These values populate a report. I want to do something like:

```
def firstCalc = resultOne.ticketsValue
def secondCalc = resultTwo.ticketsValue
def percentage = (secondCalc/firstCalc*100) + "%"
table.addData([metric:"Percentage", value: percentage])
```

However, I am unsure as to how to access these values from inside the .eachRow()

Comment: eachRow returns nothing.  what would you resultOne/Two expect to be? why are you overwriting your data with reportMetricsWithValues in the second pass? do you want to have the percentage once at the end or for each row?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access local variables outside their scope.  Define the variables outside the scope of `eachRow`.  For example:

```
def firstCalc = 0
def secondCalc = 0

db.eachRow(firstQuery, ["${startDate} 00:00:00".toString(),  ${endDate} 23:59:59".toString()]) {
    String ticketsMetric = it.metricName
    String ticketsValue = it.ticketValue.intValue()
    firstCalc += it.ticketValue.intValue()
    reportMetricsWithValues[ticketsMetric] = ticketsValue
    table.addData([metric:ticketsMetric, value: ticketsValue])
}

db.eachRow(secondQuery, ["${startDate} 00:00:00".toString(), "${endDate} 23:59:59".toString()]) {
    String ticketsMetric = it.metricName
    String ticketsValue = it.ticketValue.intValue()
    secondCalc += it.ticketValue.intValue()
    reportMetricsWithValues[ticketsMetric] = ticketsValue
    table.addData([metric:ticketsMetric, value: ticketsValue])
}

def percentage = (secondCalc/firstCalc*100) + "%"
table.addData([metric:"Percentage", value: percentage])
```